# Hadoop: how to access (many) photo images to be processed by map/reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have 10M+ photos saved on the local file system. Now I want to go through each of them to analyze the binary of the photo to see if it's a dog. I basically want to do the analysis on a clustered hadoop environment. The problem is, **how should I design the input for the map method?** let's say, in the map method, 
`new FaceDetection(photoInputStream).isDog()` is all the underlying logic for the analysis.

Specifically, 
Should I upload all of the photos to `HDFS`? Assume yes,

1. how can I use them in the `map` method?
2. Is it ok to make the input(to the `map`) as a text file containing all of the photo path(in `HDFS`) with each a line, and in the map method, load the binary like: `photoInputStream = getImageFromHDFS(photopath);` (Actually, *what is* the right method to load file from HDFS during the execution of the map method?)

It seems I miss some knowledges about the basic principle for `hadoop`, `map/reduce` and `hdfs`, but can you please point me out in terms of the above question, Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? Actually I am trying to do something similar but I don't have much idea on how to proceed

Answer (score 18):

> how can I use them in the map method?

The major problem is that each file is going to be in one file. So if you have 10M files, you'll have 10M mappers, which doesn't sound terribly reasonable. You may want to considering  pre-serializing the files into [`SequenceFiles`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.22.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.html) (one image per key-value pair). This will make loading the data into the MapReduce job native, so you don't have to write any tricky code. Also, you'll be able to store **all** of your data into one SequenceFile, if you so desire. Hadoop handles splitting SequenceFiles quite well.

Basically, the way this works is, you will have a separate Java process that takes several image files, reads the ray bytes into memory, then stores the data into a key-value pair in a SequenceFile. Keep going and keep writing into HDFS. This may take a while, but you'll only have to do it once.

---

> Is it ok to make the input(to the map) as a text file containing all of the photo path(in HDFS) with each a line, and in the map method, load the binary like: photoInputStream = getImageFromHDFS(photopath); (Actually, what is the right method to load file from HDFS during the execution of the map method?)

This is not ok if you have any sort of reasonable cluster (which you should if you are considering Hadoop for this) and you actually want to be using the power of Hadoop. Your MapReduce job will fire off, and load the files, but the mappers will be running data-local to the text files, not the images! So, basically, you are going to be shuffling the image files everywhere since the JobTracker is not placing tasks where the files are. This will incur a significant amount of network overhead. If you have 1TB of images, you can expect that a lot of them will be streamed over the network if you have more than a few nodes. This may not be so bad depending on your situation and cluster size (less than a handful of nodes).

If you do want to do this, you can use the [`FileSystem`](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.22.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) API to create files (you want the `open` method).

Comment: Amazing! specific for the SequenceFile solution, it seems a hadoop-off java process. I would rather try this one, but do you mind making a code example for generating it by loading a local image and get it onto the hdfs? this is probably a more completed solution for others also. More interesting but not necessary, the process for the SequenceFile generation and uploading it to HDFS could be another hadoop job, right? Once again, this is a very dedicated and professional answer! so appreciated!

Comment: A separate question further addressing this: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8754154/844068)

Comment: I was going through the code for [DistCp](http://goo.gl/k95cd) and it has `It takes at least two cmdline parameters. A source URL and a destination URL. It then essentially does an "ls -lR" on the source URL, and writes the output in a round-robin manner to all the map input files`. In DistCp also data locality is not considered. In the mapper the data is read from the source (which can be on a different node) and then written to the target (which is on a different cluster). There will be a lot of inter-node traffic when the data to be copied across clusters is huge. Not sure how to tackle it.

Comment: Also, check out [CombineFileInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.java) which combines files into input split and has takes data locality into considerations.

Answer (score 8):

> `I have 10M+ photos saved on the local file system.`

Assuming it takes a sec to put each file into the sequence file. It will take ~115 days for the conversion of individual files into a sequence file. With parallel processing also on a single machine, I don't see much improvement because disk read/write will be a bottle neck with reading the photo files and writing the sequence file. Check this Cloudera article on [small files problem](http://goo.gl/xgOmZ). There is also a reference to a script which converts a tar file into a sequence file and how much time it took for the conversion.

Basically the photos have to be processed in a distributed way for converting them into sequence. Back to Hadoop :)

According to the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> As a rule of thumb, each file, directory, and block takes about 150 bytes. So, for example, if you had one million files, each taking one block, you would need at least 300 MB of memory.

So, directly loading 10M of files will require around 3,000 MB of memory for just storing the namespace on the NameNode. Forget about streaming the photos across nodes during the execution of the job.

There should be a better way of solving this problem.

---

Another approach is to load the files as-is into HDFS and use [CombineFileInputFormat](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.java) which combines the small files into a input split and considers data locality while calculating the input splits. Advantage of this approach is that the files can be loaded into HDFS as-is without any conversion and there is also not much data shuffling across nodes.

Comment: It should take a lot less than a second to process a image file that is a few MB. Still, good point. You could definitely write a M/R job that did this. You can do 1 million at a time so you don't blow up the name node.

Comment: Also, 3000MB isn't that much (obviously depending on your hardware). 16GB per node is very common and if you are running your namenode by itself, that's a lot of files! One cluster I worked with had 96GB.. that was nice :)

Comment: @orangeoctopus - any idea what's the limit factor for the # of files namenode can handle? I was not sure if namenode can handle 3GB of namespace. Something interesting from the Cloudera article `Going forward it’s best to design your data pipeline to write the data at source direct into a SequenceFile, if possible, rather than writing to small files as an intermediate step.`

Comment: I agree with you completely in terms of best practices. SequenceFiles are awesome and solve so many problems! The largest deployment I worked on had 32GB of RAM and the NameNode was using about 16GB of heap.

Answer (score 0):

I was on a project a while back (2008?) where we did something very similar with Hadoop.  I believe we initially used HDFS to store the pics, then we created a text file that listed the files to process.  The concept is that you're using map/reduce to break the text file into pieces and spreading that out across the cloud, letting each node process some of the files based on the portion of the list that they receive.  Sorry I don't remember more explicit details, but this was the general approach.