# Hadoop: Example process to generating a SequenceFile with image binaries to be processed in map/reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Following [Hadoop: how to access (many) photo images to be processed by map/reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752772/hadoop-how-to-access-many-photo-images-to-be-processed-by-map-reduce) question, where [orangeoctopus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352268/orangeoctopus) provides a reasonable direction to load the image binaries and collect them into `SequenceFiles` to feed the mapper.

Think this could be useful for the others also, as a local java process or probably a hadoop job in case of vast amount image files, I created this separate question to look for the example for the implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: Please let us know how this turns out (in a comment). I've never done such a thing, but thought the approach was reasonable.

Comment: Hi Leslie, did you have any success with this? Please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) - Chapter 4 has some samples for reading/writing sequence files. Here is the [code](http://examples.oreilly.com/0636920010388/ch04.zip) for the same. Go through the code and change it for the binary images as input for the sequence file.