# Satellite Image Processing using HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hive, apache-pig

How to Store/Upload Satellite Imagery `( *.TIFF , *.GeoTiff *.Jpeg format )` into `HDFS`?
How to break the stored Satellite Imagery into Tiles?
How to Store that Tiles into HIVE meta store?
How to perform simple querying that stored data using PIG or `HBase` ? 
How to perform simple Image Processing of the stored Satellite Imagery using `MapReduce` Program ?

Comment: Your problem has less to do with Hadoop. It's mostly general programming

Comment: @VusP  Yes may be you are right .. but still my question remains the same..!
how to actually play/manipulate the data/Image using HIVE , HBase or PIG.?? thanks

Comment: @Rijulsahu What do you want to do with the images?In the current form your question is like,"Ok,I have these images.I have Hadoop.Now what can I do combining them".Please be a bit more clear,like,"I want to analyse the set of images for so-and-so purpose".If I have a set of logs,my goal would be something like,I need to generate stats for checking out how many times a particular word was repeated.Generally Java programs can manipulate images using libraries.So you just have to incorporate that in you MapReduce Code.Hadoop is just providing you a way to leverage all that massive amount of data.

Comment: @Rijulsahu [Check these links too](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=process+images+with+hadoop&rlz=1C1CHMO_enIN554IN554&oq=process+images+with+hadoop&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.7048j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Please read below blog. It explains how we can implement a new custom input format to read image files using map-reduce http://worldofbigdata-inaction.blogspot.in/2017/02/processing-images-in-hadoop-using.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop provides for `SequenceFiles` as an alternative to handle small files. In order to handle images please check this link [Processing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752772/hadoop-how-to-access-many-photo-images-to-be-processed-by-map-reduce) and also a cloudera [post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/).

Edit:

[HIPI](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/) : is a library for Hadoop's MapReduce framework that provides an API for performing image processing tasks.

Comment: Please read below blog. It explains how we can implement a new custom input format to read image files using map-reduce http://worldofbigdata-inaction.blogspot.in/2017/02/processing-images-in-hadoop-using.html

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is to treat the image as a matrix.
I would generate a flat file with tuples following this format:

```
(x coord, y coord, value)
```

This way you can apply many image manipulations (rotate, substract 2 images, indentify connected components, do some border detection...).

About the technology, I would start using flat files in the HDFS and playing with Pig.

Here is an example of matrix multiplication using this format:
http://importantfish.com/one-step-matrix-multiplication-with-hadoop/

Comment: Thanks Arutaku for generous reply. 
Somhow i managed to upload a *.TIF file ( satellite Imagery of 524 MB) in HDFS. now again my question is how to Play with this data/image using HBase, HIVE or PIG (eco systems of Hadoop ).. pls guide..

Comment: If I were you, I would start using PIG + Flat files in HDFS instead of HIVE + HBase. For example, you can perform a binarization using "FOREACH ... GENERATE" command, and then detect connected components... or whatever you need ;-)